# Is it possible to save MHTML with scripts included?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, mhtml

There is a feature in Chromium that allows to save a page as MHTML file. But the browser removes scripts from pages, and all popular extensions do that.

Is it possible to enable scripts saving in MHTML? Maybe not bundle to the result file but at least save "script" tags as is?